# How do I import pre built in components from a cdn js?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am trying to use some pre-builtin react component from a library called [ant design](https://ant.design/components/button/). Also, I would like to call the react and the component library through a cdnjs(don't wish to use webpack or else). How could I accomplish it? My approaches are like below and it's not working for me.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/antd/3.1.6/antd.min.css" />
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react-dom.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.21.1/babel.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/antd/3.1.6/antd.min.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <script type="text/babel">
import Button from 'antd/lib/button';

class Greeting extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (<p><Button type="primary">Primary</Button></p>);
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(
    <Greeting />,
    document.getElementById('root')
)
</script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need to import, because when you use prebuilt version, it's already injected into a global variable call 'antd' (just like React)

I also updated a little bit your scripts because for React you need . the umd version and antd needs the with locale version.

However, using prebuilt version is **strongly NOT RECOMMENDED** be careful.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/antd/dist/antd.css" />
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.21.1/babel.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/moment/min/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/antd/dist/antd-with-locales.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <script type="text/babel">
            const { Button } = antd;

            class Greeting extends React.Component {
                render() {
                    return (<p><Button type="primary">Primary</Button></p>);
                }
            }
            ReactDOM.render(
                <Greeting />,
                document.getElementById('root')
            )
</script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your recommendation is really acceptable. But I want to split my app into two-part, login.html and other(index.html), Using webpack with Django, In the login don't expect much more code and functionality. So I would like to try a simple page with react and antd.

Comment: Just keep in mind, importing prebuilt version means importing everything, (checkbox, table, accordion etc) the file would be unecessary large

Comment: You are right, I am also thinking some other method of a separate app for the login page(Maybe it's a wrong solution). Actually, I want multiple HTML files with webpack and djnago. It's really difficult for me to handle the multiple HTML from a Django template(Any reference would be applicable).

Comment: Change react cdn version to 16.8.6 if it still shows the same error.(To future readers)

Comment: How can I set an style to this component using style  prop? @Yichaoz

Answer (score 0):

To understand that you need to inspect your page and go to the console.
Then type "window" and open tree structure.

Now you can see that there is "antd" field in Window object, which is imported by cdn. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/du5fR.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/antd/dist/antd.css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.21.1/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/moment/min/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/antd/dist/antd-with-locales.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">
        class Greeting extends React.Component {
            render() {
                return (<p><antd.Button type="primary">Primary</antd.Button></p>);
            }
        }
        ReactDOM.render(
            <Greeting />,
            document.getElementById('root')
        )
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```